# Lua = operator as print

Tags: lua

In Lua, using the = operator without an l-value seems to be equivalent to a print(r-value), here are a few examples run in the Lua standalone interpreter:

```
> = a
nil
> a = 8
> = a
8
> = 'hello'
hello
> = print
function: 003657C8
```

And so on...

My question is : where can I find a detailed description of this use for the = operator? How does it work? Is it by implying a special default l-value? I guess the root of my problem is that I have no clue what to type in Google to find info about it :-)

**edit**:

Thanks for the answers, you are right it's a feature of the interpreter. Silly question, for I don't know which reason I completely overlooked the obvious. I should avoid posting before the morning coffee :-) For completeness, here is the code dealing with this in the interpreter:

```
while ((status = loadline(L)) != -1) {
  if (status == 0) status = docall(L, 0, 0);
  report(L, status);
  if (status == 0 && lua_gettop(L) > 0) {  /* any result to print? */
    lua_getglobal(L, "print");
    lua_insert(L, 1);
    if (lua_pcall(L, lua_gettop(L)-1, 0, 0) != 0)
      l_message(progname, lua_pushfstring(L,
                           "error calling " LUA_QL("print") " (%s)",
                           lua_tostring(L, -1)));
  }
}
```

**edit2**:

To be really complete, the whole trick about pushing values on the stack is in the "pushline" function:

```
if (firstline && b[0] == '=')  /* first line starts with `=' ? */
  lua_pushfstring(L, "return %s", b+1);  /* change it to `return' */
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting the [man page](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/lua.html):

> In interactive mode ... If a line starts with '=', then lua displays the values of all the expressions in the remainder of the line. The expressions must be separated by commas.

Answer (score 3):

I think that must be a feature of the stand alone interpreter. I can't make that work on anything I have compiled lua into.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a feature - the interpreter just returns the result of the statement. It's his job, isn't it?

Comment: Shouldn't it print 8 on "a = 8" then, too? I know many scriping consoles do that (python, irb, perl -d -e 0 etc.), but I just tried it LUA doesn't print the value of all statements, just "= ...".

Comment: jkramer: 12 years later, sorry for the delay. It's because Lua isn't one of the languages that treats assignment as an expression (which python etc do). Therefore, it has no return value and thus gets evaluated to `nil`. This is so Lua can accurately determine whether or not `a = b = 3` is an error lexically without needing to track newlines (because `a = <CR> b = 3` is probably a syntax error). PUC Rio simply made the decision to omit some flexibility in order to prevent the less code-inclined from shooting themselves in the foot (since Lua was created for non-coders).

Answer (score 0):

Assignment isn't an expression that returns something in `Lua` like it is in `C`.